# Contenido de DIV principal en HTML que se ajuste a la dimensión de la pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

necesito que el contenido que tengo en el div principal se ajuste al tamaño de la pantalla en la que se abra la web. Es decir, que haga escala y que siempre se vea la pantalla completa. No quiero que se reajuste y se utilice la barra para subir y bajar por la pantalla. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

En el HTML tengo esto:

```
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    </div
</body>
```

PD. No adjunto código ni CSS ni JS porque realmente no sé cómo hacerlo.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Explica mejor tu duda por favor, que tipo de contenido que dimensión ? Etc, los div son elementos en bloque y ocuparían por default todo el ancho disponible, entonces ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: El problema es que cuando haces grande o pequeña la pantalla, no se ajusta a escala. Sino que se debe hacer uso de la barra de scroll. Lo que necesito es que si tengo X dimensiones y mi pantalla se ve bien con X dimensiones, al agrandar o hacer pequeño, eso se quede fijo y se vea la pantalla completa sin necesidad de subir o bajar la barra. Espero haberlo aclarado.

Comment: Ok pero considera que para entender tu problema, poderlo reproducir y ofrecer una respuesta debes proveer un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar el siguiente estilo, lo cual indica un 100% del ancho del viewport

```
width:100vw;
```

Si esto no te sirve, puedes crear la siguiente clase:

```
.fullwidth {
    background-color:#000; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100px; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:999;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```